# Does i need different SHA1 key to perform Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, sha1

Hj. I am using google map API v2 for project. In my office, it works fine with cert_fingerprint key **1**

But when doing it in home, i got a blank google map. Trace log i can see this:

03-17 04:40:44.288  12461-12510/com.dump.dms E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: AIzaSyDEE3COcEWPZte_cpPl*********L2Cm_A
    Android Application ( < cert_fingerprint > ;< package_name >): EF:FA:C1:36:BD:FA:D6:6A:DE: ** : ** : ** :53:C8:8B:16:C1:15:C7:ED;com.dump.dms (call cert_fingerprint key **2**)

So i must to replace to cert_fingerprint key **2** . Then my app works normally.

Could anyone explain why i need 2 cert_fingerprint key like that? How can i use only one cert_fingerprint key ?

Comment: Are you downloading a debug and release version? You need a separate cert for each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When deploying your app as debug build, the problem is that at home your debug.keystore is different than at work. In your office, you used that debug.keystore to generate the SHA1 key which you used for generating the Google Maps API Key. When you deploy your app at home now, another debug.keystore is used and the key doesn't match.

The easiest way would be to copy your the debug.keystore file from your work environment and use it at home. But you can also enter multiple SHA1 keys in your Google API console like this (for every environment you use which means you need to create SHA1 keys for the debug.keystore files of all your environments):

```
AB:0A:05:...:12;com.example
CD:35:01:...:2B;com.example
```

The same problem appears when you deploy as release build (using the keystore file you need to generate when exporting your Android App as APK file)

See also: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debug-mode

Comment: If the answer helped you, please check it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. One question: What is normal in these cases or in the android development community? Having multiple api keys or sharing among my computers those files? I see that having 2 or more api keys adds complexity to my code, or I have to comment or uncomment that line when I change computer, is that right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In real work, we use only one SHA key and we share to each others. You can store share SHA key in .jks file

Comment: Lol, that was one of my mighty silly mistakes! Thanks +1

Comment: You said "But you can also enter multiple SHA1 keys in your Google API console like this" - but I can't figure out how? Can you please give a more detailed explanation how to do that? Thanks

Comment: In the Google Cloud Platform, create a new API key, then restrict it by selecting "Android Apps". There you can press the + button to add as many new package and SHA-1 fingerprint lines as you want.