# Multiple sha1 keys for Google play

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Is it possible to compile signed an application from different PC in debug mode. So for now sha1 is registered for one and after app is complied it's being shared and installed via apk file. I'm interested in ability to compile debug version from different computers.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: It seems to me that it's only configuration issue. The only thing I have is Google error code when I'm trying to use Google API in apk built on PC with Sha1 code different from the one i listed during registration. Gradle build script is the same on both PC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is possible, but this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087915/does-i-need-different-sha1-key-to-perform-google-map) can give you an idea that in deploying your app as debug build, the debug.keystore in 1st PC is different in the 2nd PC. On your 1st PC, you used that debug.keystore to generate the SHA1 key which you used for generating the Google API Key. When you deploy your app at 2nd PC, another debug.keystore is used and the key doesn't match.

The workaround is copy your debug.keystore file from your 2nd PC environment and use it at 1st PC. But you can also enter multiple SHA1 keys in your Google API console like this (for every environment you use, which means you need to create SHA1 keys for the debug.keystore files of all your environments.

Try also to check this link attached to that answer and this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings) for more information.